# What filesystem is Windows compatible with?

Tags: windows, ubuntu, filesystems, ntfs, ext4

What filesystem can Windows 7 be installed on except ntfs, because i need to change my file system via installing ubuntu and the option of making my hard drive ntfs is not available.

Also currently my filesystem is ext4

Comment: Windows 7 couldn't be installed on ext4. You can use gParted to resize and freeup some space for creating an ntfs partition.

Comment: I tried that, it does't work. I need to change it "outside" of an operating system.

Comment: @frebk: Use a boot CD (such as knopix) for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A quick google search confirms that windows 7 can only be installed on NTFS partitions. Previous versions (such as Windows XP) where able to be installed on FAT, but that's no longer possible. ext4 is not supported by Windows 7 at all.